# How to split a foreach loop in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way split the results of an eloquent search when using it in blade? I ask as I have a bootstrap carousel which is 2 slides split into 3 columns in each slide. I would like to have it so that each slide is filled out with the results of the following search:

```
 $alsoBought = Game::where('category_id', $showGames['category_id'])->paginate(6);
```

As you can see, it brings back 6 results. Is there a way to split it so that there's 3 results on each slide? Here's my slide code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        @foreach($alsoBought->take(3) as $bought)
                        <div class="col-4"><img class="w-100" src="{{ $bought['image'] }}" alt="First slide"></div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                        @foreach($alsoBought as $bought)
                            <div class="col-4"><img class="w-100" src="{{ $bought['image'] }}" alt="First slide"></div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-chunk) on the collection instead of [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-take) and pass the amount of items you want in each chunk

```
@foreach($alsoBought->chunk(3) as $three)
<div class="carousel-item @if ($loop->first) active @endif">
  <div class="row">
    @foreach($three as $bought)
      <div class="col-4"><img class="w-100" src="{{ $bought['image'] }}" alt="First slide"></div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-chunk)

The `chunk` method breaks the collection into multiple, smaller collections of a given size:

```php
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);

$chunks = $collection->chunk(4);

$chunks->toArray();

// [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a situation that you have 10 records to show in Blade but you need to show them in 2 sections, five records each. There’s a pretty nice trick how to do that in @foreach loop use `chunk`.

Try this.

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
            @foreach($alsoBought->chunk(3) as $bought)
                <div class="carousel-item @if($loop->first) {{ 'active' }} @endif">
                    <div class="row">

                        @foreach($bought as $item)
                            <div class="col-4"><img class="w-100" src="{{ $item['image'] }}" alt="First slide"></div>
                        @endforeach 

                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ok, deleted my comment.

Comment: It's fine, I trust you. I don't need proof.