# Laravel foreach blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have two div like this

```
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
```

And I Should output data from foreach half to first div and half to second div , but I should write foreach inside div, What I can do give advise...

```
@foreach($percentByRegion as $item)

@endforeach
```

Comment: put div within `foreach` loop

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Put your foreach inside the div, if you reach the half close the first div and start the second. Or split your `$percentByRegion` in your controller and run two foreachs

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377399/how-to-split-a-foreach-loop-in-laravel-blade help?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```html
@php $countData = $percentByRegion->count() @endphp

<div class="col-lg-6">
    @foreach($percentByRegion as $key => $item)
        @if(($countData / 2) < $key)
           First Div Data
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    @foreach($percentByRegion as $key=>$item)
        @if(($countData / 2) > $key)
            Second Div Data
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming there are 10 items, wouldn't that post 5 "first divs" and 5 "second divs"? As i understood the question there should be 5 items in _one_ "first div" and 5 items in _one_ "second div".

Comment: @brombeer, I appreciate your suggestion. I update my answer  as he/she actually want